# String sentinel on integer input Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I already posted the question about my example, it was different problem. I came up to another problem. When i choose option 3(multiply) i get result to be zero. And if i choose option 4, cannot divide by zero(zero is my sentinel). How can i make sentinel to be string or char when i use int to input numbers to be calculated? Here is the code.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchLoopNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbers = 0;
        int result = 0;
        int option;
        boolean quit = true;
        String done = "";

        do {
            System.out.println("CALCULATOR MENU");
            System.out.println("********** ****");
            System.out.println("\n1. Add");
            System.out.println("2. Substract");
            System.out.println("3. Multiply");
            System.out.println("4. Divide");

            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Enter your option >> ");
            option = scan.nextInt();

            while (quit) {

                switch (option) {

                    case 1:

                        System.out.print("Enter a number, type 0 when done >> ");
                        numbers = scan.nextInt();
                        if (numbers == 0) {
                            quit = false;
                        }
                        result += numbers;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        System.out.print("Enter a number, type 0 when done >> ");
                        numbers = scan.nextInt();
                        if (numbers == 0) {
                            quit = false;
                        }
                        result = numbers - result;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        System.out.print("Enter a number, type 0 when done >> ");
                        numbers = scan.nextInt();
                        if (numbers == 0) {
                            quit = false;
                        }
                        result *= numbers;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        System.out.print("Enter a number, type 0 when done >> ");
                        numbers = scan.nextInt();
                        if (numbers == 0) {
                            quit = false;
                        }
                        result = result / numbers;
                        break;

                }

            }

            System.out.println("The total is: " + result);
            System.out.println("Back to main menu ? y/n ");
            scan.nextLine();
            done = scan.nextLine();
            numbers = 0;
            result = 0;
            quit = true;

        } while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(done));
        System.out.println("Thank you for using calculator");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem was that you have initialized `result` to zero, and it's a good approach for addition and subtraction, but when it comes to multiplication it is not going to work. So, as a solution for that problem you have to set the variable as an `Integer`, so you can change it as you want inside the loop depending on what operation you are trying to do. Also, it's better because the class `Integer` allows you to assign its variable to `null`, which can be so handy in this kind of situations(e.g. better than using 0). Another problem you had was the way you declared an end of your current operation and get the result back. You used `0` as a way of stoping your loop, however, `0` can be used as a number within your calculation. Therefore, you should scan the input as a string then if the user entered `=` sign, the loop ends and it gives back the result. Then, you can also use the feature that is given to us by the `Integer` class which allows us to parse integer from a string and use them as regular numbers. Along with that, you had some syntax "errors" and declarations that you could've come with a better way of writing it.

In overall, if you wanted to make a real calculator, this is absolutely not the best approach to do it, because you may face many mathematical problems and exceptions, but its not very bad as a start.
This fix most of your problems:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchLoopNumbers {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number;
        String process = "";
        Integer result = null;
        int option = 0;
        boolean startOver = true;

        while (true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            if (startOver) {
                System.out.print("CALCULATOR MENU" + "\n"
                        + "****************" + "\n"
                        + "1. Add" + "\n"
                        + "2. Substract" + "\n"
                        + "3. Multiply" + "\n"
                        + "4. Divide" + "\n"
                        + "****************" + "\n"
                        + "Enter your option >> ");
                option = scan.nextInt();
            }

            switch (option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.print("Enter a number, or '=' to get the result >> ");
                    number = scan.next();
                    if ("=".equals(number)) {
                        process = process.replaceFirst("[ + \t]+$", " = ");
                        break;
                    } else if (result == null) {
                        result = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " + ";
                        option = 1;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        result = result + Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " + ";
                        option = 1;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                case 2:
                    System.out.print("Enter a number, or '=' to get the result >> ");
                    number = scan.next();
                    if ("=".equals(number)) {
                        process = process.replaceFirst("[- \t]+$", " = ");
                        break;
                    } else if (result == null) {
                        result = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " - ";
                        option = 2;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        result = result - Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " - ";
                        option = 2;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                case 3:
                    System.out.print("Enter a number, or '=' to get the result >> ");
                    number = scan.next();
                    if ("=".equals(number)) {
                        process = process.replaceFirst("[ * \t]+$", " = ");
                        break;
                    } else if (result == null) {
                        result = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " * ";
                        option = 3;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        result = result * Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " * ";
                        option = 3;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                case 4:
                    System.out.print("Enter a number, or '=' to get the result >> ");
                    number = scan.next();
                    if ("=".equals(number)) {
                        process = process.replaceFirst("[ / \t]+$", " = ");
                        break;
                    } else if (result == null) {
                        result = Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " / ";
                        option = 4;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        result = result / Integer.parseInt(number);
                        process += number + " / ";
                        option = 4;
                        startOver = false;
                        continue;
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("The result of " + process.replace("+ 0 ", "") + result);

            System.out.print("Back to main menu? [y/n]: ");
            if (scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                process = "";
                result = null;
                startOver = true;
            } else if (scan.next().equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you for using calculator.");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Wrong input!");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good working code, but i would like  user to enter more than 2 numbers (as many as user wants) , that's why i have problem with sentinel which is zero. Every time i multiply the result is zero because i reset the result variable, and cannot divide because of course cannot divide by 0.

Comment: I made the changes. Hope its what you needed.. @Ivanko

Comment: Its there now.. @SleepyX667

Comment: This is kind of code i wanted to do. Yesterday i was playing with Integer parse, but did not work out well. I managed to parse from string to integer to get result and i changed sentinel from 0 to q. I see that you used one while loop and if statements without do loop to go back to the main menu which is great. I have few questions. I am not familiar with replaceFirst. I see what it can do, but how does it works? Also , when you typed option = 2 , option =3 and so on in switch what does it do? I have to better understand your code, and it is very logical and helpful.

Comment: `replaceFirst(A,B)` is one of java `String` class methods, and you can use the API that is provided to us by Oracle which includes all java classes and their exact methodology. here is replaceFirst(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String) I assigned `option` to numbers 1,2,3 or 4(depending in which option the user picked) is because you asked to keep taking numbers from the user for the same operation over and over, until he finally enter's the `=` sign instead to end that switch looping and get the result back @Ivanko

Comment: Ok, I got clearer picture now. I will work more on logic of programming. When I took basic Java course in college, professor said it is the best practice to draw algorithm first or pseudo code and then to finally code. Do you think that is the best way to do it? I appreciate your help, explanations were helpful.

Comment: Well, as you know, we can print `Hello` with many different algorithms, however all of them, eventually, will do the same thing. So its important for you to know that there is no such a right or wrong way in programming. But there is some code that is more efficient, faster to compile, and easier to read by humans. Also, it is important for us as humans to work in abstract, don't go through all the details that you want your program to do, because the brain cannot process all that amount of informations at the same time.. @Ivanko

Comment: If you want to write a program, always start with the easy things first and leave the hardest to the end. think a little bit before writing some code, so you can find the best algorithm to solve your specific problem. Step-by-step approach will prevent many struggles and future headaches when we go further down to the end of our application. I wish you the best, and always remember "practice makes perfect." Good luck!
PS: read this article, it's useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205153/how-to-increase-code-qualityefficiency-and-optimization-of-code @Ivanko

Comment: If you got your answer, please hit the answer button so we don't create confusion to others. Thank you @Ivanko

Comment: You said it right step by step solutions are good way to solve bigger problems, as well as abstract thinking. All you said makes sense. I will read the link you posted. Thanks for advices and explanations. Wish all the best, and what someone would said among programmers, Happy programming ! :)

Comment: You're welcome! Please check the answer button. @Ivanko